# How to get WishList Product sku's or id's in phtml in Magento 2?

Tags: customer, magento-2.1, collection, wishlist, sku

How can I get a customer wishlist product id's or sku's collection in phtml file in magento 2.

Comment: for all customer or particular customer ?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to get wishlist from customer id

So update your class constructor like below:

```
    protected $_wishlistRepository;

    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistRepository
    ) {
        $this->_wishlistRepository= $wishlistRepository;
        ...
    }
```

Add below code for wishlist item collection

```
$wishlist = $this->_wishlistRepository->create()->loadByCustomerId($customerId, true);

$wishlist->getItemCollection();
```